# browscap.ini file and get_browser() aren't working

Tags: php, ini, browscap

**I removed the comment also from the php.ini in place of browscap but still it is not working.**

php.ini configuration file

```
[browscap]
browscap = "/Applications/mamp/conf/php7.0.0/browscap.ini"
```

and my code

```
<?php
$bro=get_browser(null,true);
print_r($bro);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I phased this problem.

Just open the **Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.1/conf/php.ini** file and uncomment this line:

```
[browscap]
browscap = /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/browscap.ini
```

And finally restart the MAMP. `get_browser()` function will work.

Let me know if you solved this problem.